# Using the system date / time in a Cron Script

Tags: bash, terminal, cron

I'm setting up a Cronjob that will backup a MySQL database I have in my server, but I don't want it to keep overwriting the same file over and over again. Instead, I want to have an array of backups to choose from, done automatically. For example:

```
## Cronjob, run May 21st, 2011:
mysqldump -u username -ppasword database > /path/to/file/21-03-2011.sql

## SAME Conjob, run May 28th, 2011:
mysqldump -u username -ppasword database > /path/to/file/28-03-2011.sql
```

And so on.

Is there any way that I can use the system date and/or time as some kind of variable in my Cronjob? If not, what are your suggestions to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 53):

You could try something like this (as glenn jackmann notes below, you have to escape all `%` characters):

```
15 11 * * * touch "/tmp/$(date +\%d-\%m-\%Y).sql"
```

To see if your particular cron will run the command out of crontab as a script in and of itself, or if you need to write a script that figures out the date as a string, and then runs your mysqldump command.

Without escaping the `%`, "cron" on Redhat Enterprise Linux 5.0 (I think) kept giving me errors about not finding a matching `)`. This is because everything after an unescaped `%` is sent to standard input of the command.

I would also take the recommendation to use ISO8601 date format (yyyy-mm-dd, which is `%F`) to make the file names order by date when sorted lexically.

Comment: Have to be careful with `date` inside a cronfile: some crons (all?) treat `%` as the end of the command. (so the `$()` was not the problem). You have to escape all percent signs: `... touch "/tmp/$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d)"` (nicer to use a date format that sorts lexicographically)

Comment: glenn jackman is correct: escaping the '%' characters in the crontab entry above works. A RHEL 5.0 crontab entry looks like this:50 11 * * * touch "/tmp/backup.$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d).sql"

Comment: It's worth noting that using a subshell doesn't work in an environment variable. So, `DATE=$( date -I )` and then using `${DATE}` later on results in using a literal `$( date -I )` in the job's command-line.

Comment: It seems that escaping of `%` is necessary on OpenSuse 42 as well.

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to use `date`.
Type `info date` or `man date` for details.

Something like the following might suit you (change the date format to your needs)

```
yourcommand > filepathandnameprefix$(date +"\%d-\%m-\%Y").extension
```

Comment: Again, be careful to escape all `%` chars inside cron.

Comment: @glenn: Oops, sure. As to the lexicographic order, I just matched the OP's date format. I personally like the ISO format, like you.

Answer (score 4):

> In order to have such a command running appropriately we will have to **escape %** and then it will run as expected.

See: http://www.ducea.com/2008/11/12/using-the-character-in-crontab-entries/

Answer (score 1):

Here's the bash script I used:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump -u user1 -p DatabaseName | gzip > BackupFolder/backup`date +%F_%T`.sql.gz
```

Files look like:

```
backup2011-03-02_15:16:46.sql.gz
```

Point the cron job at this to run nightly or whatever you prefer.

Comment: This works like a charm. Although, I don't quite understand what's happening in here. Does the backticks allow inclusion of the output of other programs or something? What about the formatting (like +%F and such)?

Comment: Yep the backticks perform command substitution where the output is substituted for the command itself. Refer to [Section 3.4.5](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html)

Here is a more comprehensive list of modifiers for data [link](http://ss64.com/bash/date.html)

Comment: Oh, wow, that's an amazing resource. It's great to always keep learning. Thank you very much for the link!

Answer (score 0):

Write a small wrapper script that utilizes the `date` command and calls your backup command.

```
#!/bin/bash
NOW=`/bin/date +"%m%d%Y-%H%M%S"`
if [[ "$?" != "0" ]]; then
 NOW="UNKNOWN_DATE"
 fi
mysqldump -u username -ppassword database > /path/to/file/$NOW.sql
if [[ "$?" != "0" ]]; then
 echo "$0: backup failed with error code $?"
 fi
```