# Cron Job - Log Each Minutes Activity

Tags: cron

I have some cron jobs set up to run, some of them each minute. I know I can log them to text files by simply putting `php /path/to/file.php > /var/logs/something.txt` but can I do this every minute? The nature of the log's output means that the log file will be very small, but I don't know how to log each minute's output to a separate file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe the output to cronolog for log file time handling. For documentation see [Cronolog Usage](http://cronolog.org/usage.html) and download [Cronolog at Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cronolog/)

General example

```
command "|/path/to/cronolog [OPTIONS] logfile-spec"
```

where logfile-spec for you could be

```
/var/log/cmdOutput_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%m.log
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by *jasonwryan* [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8584/using-the-system-date-time-in-a-cron-script), you could try something like this:

```
* * * * * bash -lc "php /path/to/file.php" > "/var/logs/something_$(date +\%Y\%m\%d-\%h\%m).txt" 2>&1
```

The `bash -lc` is here to be sure you script will be executed with the same environment as you are use to (in particular `$PATH`).